# Delete S3 Object(all versions) from primary bucket while replicating it to cross region bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a use case where our application upload backups to s3 bucket and same has been replicate to cross region bucket for disaster recovery.

Sometime backup fail to upload complete backup. In such case we have to delete already uploaded backup. But I am curious about the replication. If I am going to delete object which is currently actively replicating(in progress replication) to cross region, will it be possible to delete that object or will have to wait until complete replication of that object.

If its possible to delete object which is now replicating then what will happen to destination bucket object which is partially replicated. It should be manually deleted or how to do stuff with that?

Comment: Objects in Amazon S3 are never 'partially' created. They are either fully created or they don't exist. I'm not sure what would happen in your scenario, but I suspect that the copy of the object Version would complete even though you deleted it.

Comment: With S3 replication, both source and destination buckets must have versioning enabled. When you delete an object in a versioned bucket, you're not actually deleting the object. You're adding a delete marker. So, I'd expect the replication to continue unhindered.

Comment: The object and all of it's object versions(along with delete marker) are getting deleted in our case. So, I am finding formal answer whether to wait for replication to happen completely before deleting or not. I am trying to catch up case where replication is happening and would try to delete object with all versions.

Comment: Hello Guy's, I have tested delete object(all object version) while in active replication. We can delete object while in active replication. The replication of that object aborts and partial copied object in replicated bucket deletes automatically.

Comment: Great! Feel free to add that as an Answer to your own Question. It will help future readers.